# Android Places api : The provided API key is invalid

Tags: google-maps-api-3

While hit on https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?location=18.568807,73.7750902&radius=10000&key=api_key(server)&input=feegusson%20college url , it will give me following error.

```
{
"error_message": "The provided API key is invalid.",
"predictions": [

],
"status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I am unable to generate server key for google place api. Because there is no option to choose Server key in google developer console. That is why i have chosen "IP addresses" and give 219.91.159.238 default ip. I don't know if it works

Comment: What exactly is your question? The error message seems pretty clear?

Comment: Yeah your key part is not an api key, it is api_key(server)

Comment: Why? there is option to create api key in developer console.. One api key is created and can be enabled for google places also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got the solution,

Earlier, I have generated wrong server key

Answer : I made new project in developer console and created new server key. and its working. thanks for answers

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I was also experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=WriteYourKeyHere&callback=myMap

Please Try This and for generating API Use below links..

[Get API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

[image]In developer console there is an option for credentials and you could create credentials.

Click Create credential->API Key. You will get API key. Now enable google places api and put your api key in your url. You will get the result